# Copy objects (array command) with increasing distance in AutoCAD

Tags: autocad

I try to draw a field of circles. The density of the circles (ratio area circle to interstitial space) should increase continuously (gradient). Has anyone an idea how to do that, maybe using other programs scripts etc. The result should look like the picture, just with continuous changing space between circles.   [image]

Comment: I've managed to make a *.txt file that contains the xy coordinates of all my points. But I was not able to use the AutoCAD 'script' command to run this file saved as *.scr  with POINT in the first line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a *.scr file is not a problem, make it like this

```
CIRCLE
0,0
20

0,100


0,200


100,300
```

That is - after each coordinate make 2 blank lines (first line is for diameter, second to execute command "circle" again)

It would be the same if you were writing

```
CIRCLE
0,0
20
CIRCLE
0,100
20
CIRCLE
0,200
20
CIRCLE
100,300
20
```